# q/kdb+ new version 4.0 parse error reading large tables from previous version

Tags: parsing, runtime-error, load, kdb

Is there any solution other than saving as csv and reloading in the new version...

```
KDB+ 4.0 2020.05.04 Copyright (C) 1993-2020 Kx Systems
m64/ 8(16)core 32768MB georgelovas ... 127.0.0.1 EXPIRE 2020.08.26

'parse `:../marketdata/tx
  [0]  (.Q.l)
```

With the old version...

```
KDB+ 3.6 2019.08.20 Copyright (C) 1993-2019 Kx Systems
m64/ 8(16)core 32768MB ... 127.0.0.1 EXPIRE 2020.08.26 
q)count tx
2521171492
q)
```

Table info...

```
q)meta tx
c     | t f a
------| -----
DATE  | d    
TICKER| s    
FIELD | s    
VALUE | f    
q)t
DATE       TICKER        FIELD                         VALUE       
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1998.01.31 XXXXXXX INDEX FIELD_1                       -881        
1998.01.31 XXXXXXX INDEX FIELD_2                       -604        
1998.01.31 XXXXXXX INDEX FIELS_3                        0           
1998.01.31 XXXXXXX INDEX FIElD_4                1.998031e+07
1998.02.28 XXXXXXX INDEX FIELD_1                       -544        
1998.02.28 XXXXXXX INDEX FIELD_2                       -475        
1998.02.28 XXXXXXX INDEX FIELS_3                        0           
1998.02.28 XXXXXXX INDEX FIElD_4                1.998041e+07
```

Answer (score 1):

I see you are using:

```
KDB+ 4.0 2020.05.04
```

After reading the release notes, in the 2020.06.18 version there was a bug fix where reading an object exceeding 2GB in serialized form as part of a compound object from a single file was throwing a parse error since 3.7t 2019.10.22. Your version that works is 3.6. So this may be the answer to your problem.

Have you tried using \l from within a q session to load the table ?
The error your output seems to be showing is when loading the data from the command line.
Can you give more information on what the table consists of, meta etc.?
We may need more information around the table meta to replicate.
Can you tell us what the tx looks like?

Comment: updated original post with table meta and sample data... I did some tests and was able to load data up to around 11G when saved using v4.0 with parse error when greater. Seems like a major bug to have in a prod release?.

Comment: Have you tried updating your kdb to the 2020.06.18 version ?